# How do you pass a another control into a user-created ASP.NET control as a parameter in its decleration using the ID of the other control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create a control (`MyControl`) which does things to other controls on the page it's on. It has a property:

```
public property System.Web.UI.Control SomeOtherControl;
```

I want to be able to set this property from the ASPX page that uses the control. Right now, the only way I can do it is in the `Page_Load` of the code-behind:

```
MyControl.SomeOtherControl = TheOtherControl;
```

Instead of having to do this on the code-behind of every page that uses `MyControl`, I want do just do this on the ASPX page:

```
<xyz:MyControl SomeOtherControl="TheOtherControlsID" />
```

In order to do this I tried using the `Page.FindControl()` method on the ID string to find the referenced control when `MyControl` initializes, but it only searches the page's top-level controls. I could write my own recursive `FindControl()`, but I figure there must be a better way to do this, and I'm worried about the performance of something like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A recursive FindControl is probably a lot faster then you might believe. I've never even been able to measure a millisecond worth of different in processing time, even with hundreds of controls.